# Определенность псевдозаписей old и new для строковых триггеров в oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Изучаю триггеры по статье и столкнулся с не пониманием момента. Итак, есть две таблицы, на первой пара триггеров:

```
CREATE TABLE DATA_TABLE
(
    ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    NM VARCHAR2(50),
    ROD VARCHAR2(50),
    INRW DATE,
    COST NUMBER
)
/

CREATE TABLE LOG_TABLE
(
    ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    IDD VARCHAR2(50),     
    ROD VARCHAR2(50),     
    CONS NUMBER,
    ITOG NUMBER
)
/

CREATE SEQUENCE SV
    START WITH 5
    INCREMENT BY 1
/
CREATE SEQUENCE TRG
    START WITH 8000
    INCREMENT BY 1
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INS_ID_TRG
    BEFORE INSERT ON DATA_TABLE
    FOR EACH ROW        
DECLARE    
BEGIN       
    SELECT TRG.NEXTVAL 
        INTO :NEW.ID 
    FROM DUAL;    
END INS_ID_TRG;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MyTrigger
    AFTER INSERT ON DATA_TABLE
    FOR EACH ROW        
DECLARE    
BEGIN    
    INSERT INTO LOG_TABLE(LOG_TABLE.ID, LOG_TABLE.IDD, LOG_TABLE.ROD, LOG_TABLE.CONS)
        VALUES(SV.NEXTVAL, :NEW.NM, :NEW.ROD, :NEW.ID);    
END MyTrigger;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MyTrigger_2
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF COST ON DATA_TABLE
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (new.COST > 10000)     
DECLARE    
BEGIN    
    UPDATE LOG_TABLE
        SET LOG_TABLE.ITOG = :new.COST + :old.COST
    WHERE LOG_TABLE.CONS = :old.ID;    
END MyTrigger_2;
/
```

Теперь внесем в таблицу данных строку:

```
INSERT INTO TSTTRIG (NM, ROD, INRW, COST)
        VALUES ('BOB',  'DUMMY', TO_DATE('9-11-1989', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 24734)
```

В итоге в таблицах будут значения:

DATA_TABLE:

```
    ID NM       ROD          INRW        COST
  8000 BOB      DUMMY        09.11.1989  24734
```

LOG_TABLE:

```
    ID IDD      ROD         CONS       ITOG
     5 BOB      DUMMY       8000       NULL
```

И объяснение:

> Но вот почему поле ITOG таблицы LOG_TABLE содержит NULL? Странно, не
>   правда ли? Ведь условие 24734 > 10000 дает TRUE! Да, триггер MyTrigger_2
>   свою работу выполнил! Но дело в том, что псевдозапись :new для
>   триггеров по INSERT не определена, то есть содержит - NULL! Отсюда
>   NULL + 24734 = NULL!

Я вот не понял, как так может :new быть не определен. Я бы предположил, что :old может быть не определен. Это на сайте ошибка или я чего-то не понимаю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала отрабатывает “before trigger” который пытается изменить пустую на тот момент таблицу, а уже потом идёт вставка записи в “After trigger” и “itog” в этом триггере не вставляется, поэтому он остаётся пустым

Comment: Возможно я накосячил с переносом фрагментов кода с сайта по первой ссылке при гуглинге "Первые шаги триггеры" (шаги 110-116). Именно потому что запутался во всех этих вариантах :( Но в цитате видно, что речь не про Itog, а именно про :new. А ваш ответ вероятно технически верный, но не обращает внимание на объяснение из статьи, котороя я и хочу понять.

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов а дайте ссылку на вашу статью

Comment: @Viktorov просто не был уверен как тут к ссылкам на внешние ресурсы относятся. [Сюда тык](http://www.firststeps.ru/sql/oracle/r.php?115). Цитата из вопроса в самом конце.

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов похоже, что в статье двойная ошибка. 1) `Null` получается из-за очередности работы триггеров. Даже если заменить выражение `new + old` на константу, останется все равно `null`. 2) Для инсертов не определено значение именно у `old`

Comment: @Viktorov, да, слабоватая статья по ссылке какая-то...